# Django 2.0 and DRF 3.7.7 routers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, url-routing

I'm using Django 2.0 and DRF 3.7.7(novice with both) and trying to add URL patterns in app_config/urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^submit_free_account', SubmitFreeAccount, 'SubmitFreeAccount')

app_name = 'app_config'  #the weird code

urlpatterns = [
    path('getSourcesNodes', GetSourcesNodes.post, name='GetSourcesNodes'),
    path('getAppsNodes', GetAppsNodes.post, name='GetAppsNodes'),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

And in main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('config/', include('app_config.urls', namespace='app_config')),
]
```

So when I trying to request config/submit_free_account I have 404 errors with strange URL patterns tried by Django:

```
config/ ^$ [name='api-root']
config/ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
```

How to add router URL patterns correctly in Django 2.0?

Comment: `router.registet` is supposed to be used with viewsets. Is SubmitFreeAccount a viewsets? Show the code.

Comment: SubmitFreeAccount  is APIView (supposed to be standard class for DRF views)

Comment: You don't need a router for a view, only a viewset. Use a standard `path()` or `url()` to define the route.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, but if this way I have an error: "__init__ takes 1 positional arguments but 2 were given". And it is DRF, so I don't want to have as_view() method. So I can't have CLASS based view.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use as_view. That is how you register a class based view.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, I just thought that DRF APIViews don't support this method, but now I fixed some mistakes in my code and this has started to work. Thanks. Without your comment, I wouldn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

see: [Django REST Framework URLs with Django 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005264/django-rest-framework-urls-with-django-2-0)

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
# change to (see user8814926's answer):
router.register('submit_free_account', SubmitFreeAccount, 'SubmitFreeAccount')

app_name = 'app_config'  #the weird code

urlpatterns = [
    path('getSourcesNodes', GetSourcesNodes.post, name='GetSourcesNodes'),
    path('getAppsNodes', GetAppsNodes.post, name='GetAppsNodes'),

    #add this:
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

so summarize it:

- don't use the regex
- include the routes not by adding to the list, but instead with the include method as shown above

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
router.register(r'^submit_free_account', SubmitFreeAccount, 'SubmitFreeAccount')
```

to

```
router.register('submit_free_account', SubmitFreeAccount, 'SubmitFreeAccount')
```

Comment: I tried this, also thought that this didn't suppose the regex expression, but the situation wasn't changed.