# Django REST Framework URLs with Django 2.0

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-2.0

I'm trying to set up Django REST Framework with Django 2.0 project which means `url(r'^something/' ...` has been replaced with `path(something/ ...`.

I'm trying to work out how to set up my `rest_framework` patterns.

This is what I have:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'regulations', api.RegulationViewSet)
router.register(r'languages', api.LanguageViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    ...
]
```

If I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/regulations` I simply get:

> Page not found (404)

How should I set up my `urlpatterns`?

Comment: `url()` has *not* been replaced. It is still valid. `path()` is an *alternative*. Note, however, you don't seem to have defined a URL for /regulations.

Comment: @DanielRoseman But he has registered `regulations` with the `router`. He needs to implement it in the `urlpatterns` with `include` or by concatenating: `urlpatterns += router.urls`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    ...
]
```

with `path('', include(router.urls)),` you can get:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/regulations/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/languages/
```

with

```
path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

you can get:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-auth/{other paths}
```

Comment: This will result in `http://localhost:8000/api-auth/regulations`. Also `rest_framework.urls` is right too, but it is for the authentication routes provided by Django REST Framework. The `routers.urls` should be included under another path.

Comment: Then you should remove the last sentence and add explanation.

Answer (score 3):

After registering the `router` you have to include it in the `urlpatterns`. The way how @Ykh suggested is technically correct, but with regards to content is missing the point.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # here you include your router
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    # here you include the authentication paths
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

Now you'll have the following routes:

```
http://localhost:8000/regulations/
http://localhost:8000/languages/
```

plus:

```
http://localhost:8000/api-auth/{other paths}
```